# Android Studio StyleRes annotation gives warning on Kotlin var

Tags: android-studio, annotations, kotlin

I have a publicly visible Int to hold the current application theme.

```
var themeId: Int = R.style.AppTheme
    private set
```

If I annotate the value with `@StyleRes`

```
@StyleRes var themeId: Int = R.style.AppTheme
    private set
```

I get a warning

> This annotation does not apply for type void; expected int or long

If I change the variable to `val`, the error is not displayed.
I can also get rid of the error by adding the `@JvmField` annotation, but this removes the ability to have the private setter.

Am I using the annotation incorrectly, or is this a problem with Kotlin on Android Studio?

Edit:

The getter can be annotated

```
var themeId: Int = R.style.AppTheme
    private set
    @StyleRes get
```

Comment: have you tried `@field:StyleRes` or `@get:StyleRes`?

Comment: Both give the same message as before.

Comment: how about `private @StyleRes var themeId: Int = R.style.AppTheme`?

Comment: The same message still occurs. I did just realise that I can annotate the getter, as added to the question.

Comment: so , it can working as you expected. it doesn't matter. since kotlin has a lot of features has not ready done.

Comment: I know that it doesn't really matter, I just wanted to check if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi, I want to tell you do not pursue perfection just do it. if you found the best one just replace it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue, see [KT-16506](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16506).